# UISegmentedControl with multiple strings in each segmented index

Tags: uisegmentedcontrol, swift4

I am trying to show 2 strings of text in each segmented index instead of one long text. Currently the view looks like this[image]

I want another string below "Repeat task" and "One time task" as marked by the red line in the image. Currently my model is

```
class SegmentedControlItems:NSObject{
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String

    init(title:String, subtitle:String) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }
}
```

And the code in my table view header is

```
        let items:[SegmentedControlItems] = {
            let item1 = SegmentedControlItems(title: "Repeat task", subtitle: "2 left")
            let item2 = SegmentedControlItems(title: "One time task", subtitle: "3 left")
            return [item1, item2]
        }()

        let segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {

            let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: items.map({
                $0.title
            }))
            segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.44, green:0.75, blue:0.27, alpha:1.0)
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
            segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return segmentedControl
        }()
        headerView.addSubview(segmentedControl)
```

I am creating all the views programmatically in swift4.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found something like this with Objective C [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30589653/7084910)

For iOS 11 and Swift 4:

For multiline, try this. It may help you.

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISegmentedControl.self]).numberOfLines = 0

for i in 0..<items.count {

     var str = items[i].title
     if items[i].subtitle != "" {
       str += "\n\(items[i].subtitle)"
     }

     let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [:])
     myMutableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:items[i].title.characters.count + 1, length:items[i].subtitle.characters.count))
     myLabel[i].attributedText = myMutableString
     mySegment.setTitle(myMutableString.string, forSegmentAt: i)
}
```

> Output look like this (In UILabel its working, but not in UISegmentControl) Hope someone will do that:

[image: In UILabel its work but not in UISegmentControl]

[image]